# VS 2015 InstallShield LE - Recursively include subfolders

Tags: recursion, visual-studio-2015, installshield

I am trying to create an InstallShield msi that installs 2 websites.  Both sites include MANY folders with subfolders with subfolders.  Adding them all manually to the Files area 'Destination computers folders' area, would royally suck.  In the old version of Microsoft Installer that used to come with Visual Studio, I was able to drag/drop a parent folder and all the files/folders would recursively add themselves to my installer.  How do I do that in InstallShield LE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain about the LE product version, but in the full version of InstallShield Professional or Premium you can **right click**  within a component you have created and select 'dynamic file linking'. You can then specify a parent folder and select the link to include subfolders. You can also specify a file filter for inclusion and exclusion. Like you may not want to include .pdb debug files with your product, so you add that extension to the exclusion list.

Note that you can potentially run into problems if your upgrade path includes minor upgrades where the subfolders are not upgraded properly.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: That is fantastic!  Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanHansen I use this feature frequently with folders that contain large number of image files. I would not recommend this for .dll, ocx, exe, chm, and other significant files where ensuring proper upgrade paths is critical. Also, if this is helpful please mark as solution.

Comment: I am using InstallShield to install a large Website that contains lots of folders and subfolders for scripting.  

When you say "a component" that I have created, where are you talking about?  I presumed in the "Files" area, but I don't see any way of selecting "dynamic file linking'

Comment: I just downloaded InstallShield Professional.  I immediately figured out how to create Dynamic Links.  Thanks for the help.